# How unset a lot of environment variables

Tags: linux, unset

Have any way to unset different variables using a one command?

```
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
unset FTP_PROXY
unset ALL_PROXY
unset NO_PROXY
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more context on exactly what you're trying to do and what Linux operating system you are using?

Comment: Yes @JosephIdziorek, I wish use one command like unset *_PROXY, but unset not accept wildcards.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`unset` takes multiple variables:

```
unset HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY ALL_PROXY NO_PROXY
```

Comment: It should be the only way. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, this does not work if the variables you want to unset is stored in a variable itself, e.g. `unset "$UNSET_VARS"` does not work..

Comment: That passes them all as a single parameter. You need each variable as a separate argument, e.g. by not quoting it, or preferably by using an array in the first place

Answer (score 14):

A little bit late, but anyway. Depending on your variable pattern you can shorten your unset:

1. List your variables. For example, depending on your scope you can do it with `env` or `compgen -v`.
2. Filter for desired variables. For example with `grep` or `sed`.
3. Pass the variables to `unset`.

For example in your case it can be:

```sh
unset $(compgen -v | grep "_PROXY$")
```

It's not exactly one command, but it imitates `unset *_PROXY`, as you requested in your comment.

Comment: I added the `-i` argument to the `grep` command to ignore case. I found I had a number of proxy related environment variables set which were also lower case. As it's written above it'll only catch the ones with proxy in all uppercase characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using [babashka](https://github.com/borkdude/babashka):

```clj
bb -o '(->> (System/getenv)
            keys
            (filter #(str/ends-with? % "_PROXY"))
            (map #(str "unset " %)))' | 
  source /dev/stdin
```